# Using createDelegate in extjs

Tags: extjs4

Here is my first try to pass user defined arguments to a handler function in extjs(4.0.1) in IE9. I have the below code, but it throws up an error stating that `SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'createDelegate'`. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Please help.

Js file:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

    var appendBooleanOrInsertionIndex = 0; 
    var myButtonHandler = function(item,a, b, arg){
           alert(a + " "+ b);
        };

var myButton = new Ext.Button({
       id : 'myButton',
       //renderTo : 'mybutton',
       text : 'Save',
       handler : myButtonHandler.createDelegate(this, ['Hi', 'Kart'], appendBooleanOrInsertionIndex),
       scope : this
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ext stopped adding logic to native class prototypes in Ext 4. Use [Ext.Function.bind](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Function-method-bind) or [Ext.Function.pass](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Function-method-pass).

Comment: Hi..Thanks for the reply. I tried both bind and pass but got the error SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'apply'  in the ext-all-debug.js file. Not sure what it is. Pls help...

Comment: How are you calling bind/pass? This should work `handler: Ext.Function.pass(myButtonHandler, ['Hi, 'Kart'])`. Do you have any other libraries included that might be messing with the Array prototype?

Comment: Hi wantok, I was so stupid that I missed a comma in the function syntax which resulted in the error. What u had said it correct. Using `Ext.Function.pass` did the trick. The corrected code is in my answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

the corrected code is as below:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {


    var myButtonHandler = function(a, b){//alert("-->");
           alert(a + " "+ b);
        };

        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            width: 800,
            height: 300,
            layout: 'column',
            title: 'Container Panel',
            //html: 'parent panel',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    id: 'mbutton',
                    text : 'My Button',
                    handler : Ext.Function.pass(myButtonHandler, ['Hi', 'Kart!!!!'])
                }
            ]
        });
});
```